# Como enviar parâmetros para um servidor?

Tags: android, servidor, post, parâmetros

Eu comecei a aprender programação Android a pouquíssimo tempo. Eu programava em Java *desktop* mas nunca fiz nenhuma aplicação para se comunicar com um servidor.

Agora eu preciso de comunicar com um servidor através do método `post` numa aplicação Android. Eu consegui fazer isso, porém eu não consigo enviar parâmetros para o servidor.

O servidor deve realizar um cadastro e enviar uma resposta e ele deve receber uma imagem e alguns outros dados e eu já pesquisei e não consigo fazer isso.

Segue o meu código até agora:

```
    //Converte um InputStream em String
    private String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws Exception {
        try {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    //O código propriamente dito que se comunicará com o servidor
    private String downloadUrl(String myUrl) throws Exception {

        InputStream is = null;
        String respStr = null;

        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            respStr = readIt(is, len);

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }

        return respStr;
    }
}
```

O meu Android Studio não reconhece o `HttpClient` e nem esse `NameValuePair` e o `HttpUrlConnection` não possui o método `setEntity`. Esse é o problema. A internet só fala desse `HttpClient` e não da certo pra mim. Eu sou iniciante e não consigo continuar e eu tenho tempo para acabar . é só enviar os parâmetros para o servidor! só isso!

Answer (score 3):

O problema do Android Studio não reconhecer o `HttpClient`, é que ele ficou *deprecated* na API 22 e foi removido na API 23.

A solução que eu encontrei para trabalhar com requisições num servidor/webservice, foi usar a **okHttp**.

No próprio repositório da [okHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), tem um exemplo de como usar o `POST`.

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Deixo abaixo também um exemplo de como fazer um `GET` numa URL e armazenar em uma String.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

---

### Como incluir a OkHttp no Gradle?

Para incluir a OkHttp no Gradle, você deve abrir o `build.gradle` da aplicação e adicionar a linha dentro de *dependences*.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

Depois disso, é só clicar em `sync now` no topo da tela.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do amigo emanuelsn realmente é ótima, só para completar caso vocÇe tenha uma classe e queira que ela seja convertida para JSon direto sem aquela burocracia de ter que montar ele na mão você também pode usar a lib GSON, muito boa, ela trabalha com annotations, deixa o trabalho bem mais simples.

para utilizar ele no Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu faço utilizando parâmetros na URL, cryptografo os parâmetros e envio e faço o parse destes do lado do servidor. Para envio no envelope do POST de uma olhada nessa resposta do StackOverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288823/how-to-add-parameters-in-android-http-post

Algo assim:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/myexample.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "stackoverflow.com is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```